Fallos de React sin sentido al Transpilar sin Error en modo Desarrollo (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input)
Esta lógica funciona perfecto en modo desarrollo, pero en produccion falla y genera un error que react nunca reporta ni en modo estricto y solo se ve desde la consola, en la 'ultima línea, se ve claramente que es un problema al transpilar porque se ve el código cortado, termina en retu o algo así
const { isOpen, toggleMenu } = useIconoHamburguesa();
const { handleNavClick } = useScrollTo();

<a href="#contact" className="menu-item"
   onClick={(e) => {
     handleNavClick(e, 'contact')
}}>{content.navbar.link5}</a>(toggleMenu);

//**En el hook personalizado

export const useScrollTo = (toggleMenu) => {
//***etc

const handleNavClick = (event, targetId) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   scrollTo(targetId);
   toggleMenu();
  };

  return { scrollTo, handleNavClick }
}

Pero esto si llamo a la funcion toogle menu de esta forma si funciona y es como único no me da error.
<a href="#whyus" className="menu-item" onClick={(e) => {
    handleNavClick(e, 'whyus');
    toggleMenu();

}}>{content.navbar.link4}</a>

Por si esto fuera poco, obtengo el mismo error sin sentido con esto:
<a href="#service4" onClick={(e) => handleNavClick(e, 'service4')}>{content.navbar.sublink4}</a>

Pero si envuelvo la llamada a la función handleNavClick entre paréntesis desaparece el error y funciona en producción, de lo contrario falla con el mismo error por consola, y recalco que en modo desarrollo no pasa nada y en ningún caso el editor marca error de sintaxis.
Otro error que me encontré es este:
    <div>
    
                {
                    Object.entries(content.acercaDe.secciones).map(([key, seccion]) => (
                        <div className="acercaDe__seccion" key={key}>
                            <div className='acercaDe__seccion__titulo'>{seccion.titulo}</div>
                            <hr />
                            <p className='acercaDe__seccion__descripcion'>{seccion.descripcion}</p>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
    
    
                {
                    Object.values(content.acercaDe.secciones).map((seccion, index) => (
    
                        <div className="acercaDe__seccion" key={index}>
                            <div className='acercaDe__seccion__titulo'>{seccion.titulo}</div>
    
                            <hr />
    
                            <p className='acercaDe__seccion__descripcion'>{seccion.descripcion}</p>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
</div>

El primer bloque funciona, el segundo falla y genera el mismo error, comento q no hay error de sintaxis en ningún caso y también funciona en modo desarrollo pero falla en producción.
Alguien me puede explicar por qué pasan estas cosas? En especial la segunda y la primera pues no debería fallar de ninguna forma, acaso el transpilador de React tiene bugs? Aclaro q usé Vite para pasar a producción y React Router en el proyecto por si acaso sirve de algo esta info.

¿No hay error de sintaxis? Y qué hace un elemento JSX campando libremente sin ser asignado a una variable o retornado? Para mi, ese es un grave error de sintaxis.

Esto tambien se ve buggy const { handleNavClick } = useScrollTo, no será const { handleNavClick } = useScrollTo()?

@MauricioContreras a qué te refieres exactamente? En VSCode no me marca error de sintaxis, ojo q no estoy poniendo todo el código, solo lo que da error

@g.4 en el código está como debe ser: const { handleNavClick } = useScrollTo(); lo que al copiar me comí un pedazo, los errores de sintaxis siempre me los marca VSCode y no hay en nungún caso, ahora edito la pregunta

Creo q ya entendí a lo que se refiere Mauricio, el último bloque de código lo puse así solo de ejemplo para que se entienda que es un código jsx dentro de un div, obviamente ese código está dentro de un return, no está así al aire y con 1 de los 2, no los 2 a la vez

Pues, se necesita mas información, si pudieras compartir una versión mÍnima en un repositorio tal vez se podría depurar.

@g.4 el problema al parecer era que el ftp subía los archivos incompletos

Al parecer el problema era que el FTP subía los archivos de forma incompleta y no un problema del build
